# how to calculate difference between two timestamps _a and _b in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

how to get the difference between _a and _b ? like the difference in hours,minutes and seconds

```
@client.command()
async def timestamp(ctx, id : int,id2 : int):
    a = discord.utils.snowflake_time(id)
    b = discord.utils.snowflake_time(id2)
    _a = "{:02d} : {:02d} : {:02d}".format(a.hour, a.minute, a.second)
    _b = "{:02d} : {:02d} : {:02d}".format(b.hour,b.minute,b.second)
```

Comment: why not convert them to datetime object and subtract one from another?

Comment: and how to convert them into datetime object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

both `a` and `b` are `datetime.datetime` objects, hence we can directly find the timedelta

```py
import datetime
delta = abs(a - b) #always get the positive delta
delta = datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(delta.total_seconds())) #remove microseconds
#remove the above line if you want milliseconds
print(delta) #or str(delta)
```

This would print, the delta in `hh:mm:ss` format if the different is less than a day.

Comment: thanks for the help but there is a error :- (AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta')

Comment: if i want to get the milliseconds then how do i do that? like `hour:minute:second.millisecond`

Comment: I added a comment in my answer, simply remove the line that removes milliseconds